# iOS 8 Metal templates are broken

Tags: ios, templates

I recently signed up for the iOS developer program so I could release an app I've been developing, and decided to experiment with Apple's new Metal API. However, that has been difficult, since the Objective-C template is having an error with the

```
@import Metal
```

line in GameViewController.m (one of the files in the template), and the Swift template (which I would actually prefer to use) is unfinished and

```
import Metal
```

doesn't work. Is there an SDK I need to download or something? Or is it just my Mac? I am using the Xcode 6 beta as well as the OS X Yosemite beta.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in later betas of Xcode, try it again. Don't forget that you can't build Metal for the simulator, it only runs on the device.