# iOS Metal can't exec 'metal' (No such file or directory)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, metal

How do you compile an iOS «Metal» game in Xcode 6 with the target set to the iOS Simulator?

> error: can't exec 'metal' (No such file or directory) Command metal failed with exit code 71

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A «Metal» project cannot be compiled when the target is set to the iOS Simulator.

You have to connect a physical device and use that as your target when compiling the project.

As described in the answer on this issue: [iOS 8 Metal templates are broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231789/ios-8-metal-templates-are-broken).

**Update**: As of Xcode 11 «Metal» projects can be compiled and run on the iOS Simulator.

Comment: I'm running v6.0.1 and I'm still getting this issue

Answer (score 1):

As of Xcode 11, Metal is supported in iOS 13, tvOS 13, and watchOS 6 simulators when running on macOS 10.15 Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run metal on simulator but you can use this workaround so that it will still compile as long as you have a fallback for the graphics code like Open GL

medium.com/@jscampbell/bare-metal-working-with-metal-and-the-simulator-70e085e3a45